# an efficient logger for app-engine on android studio

Tags: java, google-app-engine, logging, android-studio

For comparison, android has a kick-ass logger, where in one line I can do

```
Log.d("TAG", "Something important is happening here.");
```

Using eclipse on app engine, I have been doing

```
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
…
//inside method
LOG.info("I don’t want to have two lines");
```

I am moving to android studio, is there a way to do something as cool as the one on android? I imagine I might have to add a dependency to Gradle. Any ideas how I might do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking. How is your logging dependent on your IDE?

But to answer your question: When using Java on AppEngine you should use `java.util.logging`. Only `java.util.logging` logs will go into the Monitoring -> Logs section of your cloud console. We're using slf4j in our projects, which is nice if you have multiple projects with different logging mechanisms but what to use the same syntax.

Actually, you could also use a different logger and write the logs to `System.out` but i don't recommend it. You should use the facilities App Engine provides.

If you must, you could do something similar as you have in Android Studio. That would probably work with a static import of a Log class and a lot of reflection / stack unwinding to get the logging class name. Since reflection is the opposite of performance, i wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, the Log you mention (the cool one) is part of the Android framework and it's independent of your IDE.

You could build your own log "utils" and either extend it or call it statically to reduce logging code.

eg.

```
public class LogAware {

    protected void log(Level level, String message){
        Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(level,message);
    }

    protected void logInfo(String message){
        log(Level.INFO,message);
    }

    protected void logFine(String message){
        log(Level.FINE,message);
    }

    protected void logWarning(String message){
        log(Level.WARNING,message);
    }

    protected void logSevere(String message){
        log(Level.SEVERE,message);
    }

    protected void logException(Exception e){
        Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,"Exception Thrown",e);
    }
```

Comment: The code example is exactly what i warned about in my answer. Not only does this code use reflection in every call to logException and log (which is bad for performance), it will also always show LogAware as the source of logging which is not what you want.